# How to map a String to a java method reference for unknown return type?

Tags: java

I want to map a `String` to a method reference. The problem is that this method can return `void` or `boolean`.

I was using `@FunctionalInterface` but seems it can have only one method (I would need one for `void` and one for `boolean`?).

Below is the code I have so far. The commented lines are what I would like to do.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface MethodParser <T1, T2> {
    public void apply(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
}

public class OperatorParser {

    public static Map<String, MethodParser> INTEGER = new HashMap<String, MethodParser>();

    public static void buildInteger() {
        MethodParser<Integer_, Integer> plus = (pObj, pValue) -> pObj.plus(pValue);
        MethodParser<Integer_, Integer> minus = (pObj, pValue) -> pObj.minus(pValue);

        // MethodParser<Integer_, Integer> grThan = (pObj, pValue) -> pObj.greaterThan(pValue);
        // MethodParser<Integer_, Integer> lessTh = (pObj, pValue) -> pObj.lessThan(pValue);

        OperatorParser.INTEGER.put("+", plus);
        OperatorParser.INTEGER.put("-", minus);

        // OperatorParser.INTEGER.put(">", grThan);
        // OperatorParser.INTEGER.put("<", lessTh);
    }

}
```

The object `Integer_` represents a integer number and has void methods (`plus(int)` and `minus(int)`) that changes the `value` of the object and `boolean` methods (`greaterThan(int)` and `lessThan(int)`) that returns a value.

The `MethodParser` interface is just one way I found to map a String to a method reference. I use it to map a given String to a method that already exists somewhere else.

**Note:** Some similar questions I have tried (these don't worked for me):

- [Can I map a String to a method in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721318/can-i-map-a-string-to-a-method-in-java)
- [Return method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499675/return-method-reference)

Comment: Can you wrap the result in `Optional` so that `void` return type can be returned as `Optional.empty` and the other one wrapped in `Optional`?

In Java functional interface terms, one is a `BiFunction` and other one is `BiConsumer` and they do not have a common parent

Comment: What the purpose of your MethodParser? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: In my code, could I change the `void` in `apply(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)` to `Optional<T1>` or something like that?

Comment: @NoDataFound I use the `MethodParser` to map a given String to a method that already exists somewhere else.

Comment: The toString() method can't be applied?

Comment: The problem is the return type of the method `void`/`boolean` (more in the future), I believe returning `String` in all the operations would break the rest of the code.

Comment: That's not the map usage I want to understand, but the MethodParser usage: what is the real purpose? Are you trying to, for example, parse some expression tree? In that case, you could return a composite object (or even Object).

Comment: @NoDataFound The `MethodParser` is not used for anything but make possible a mapping between a `String` and a method reference (I have other types such as Double_ and String_).

Answer (score 1):

Make a method for `void` and one for `boolean` and a method that includes the condition that tells when to use either.
I don't know of any method that could have 2 return types.
You Can use a POJO class instance to return multiple values with grouping.