# Simplify this if statement in JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, expression

I'm trying to simplify this if statement to avoid code repetition and if statements. I also want to be able to pass more than 2 arguments. i.e. 5+10*2/2. Any ideas?

```java
public static double randomExpressionDraft(String exp) {
    double primeResult = 0;
    double newResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) {
        if (exp.charAt(i) == '*') {
            newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) * Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
            primeResult = newResult;
            System.out.println(primeResult);
        } else if (exp.charAt(i) == '/') {
            newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) / Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
            primeResult = newResult;
            System.out.println(primeResult);
        } else if (exp.charAt(i) == '+') {
            newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) + Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
            primeResult = newResult;
            System.out.println(primeResult);
        } else if (exp.charAt(i) == '-') {
            newResult = Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i)) - Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i + 1, exp.length()));
            primeResult = newResult;
            System.out.println(primeResult);
        }
    }
    return primeResult;
}
```

Comment: one better way is that use switch, without break and in default use the two statements i.e, primeResult = newResult; and System.out.println(primeResult);

Comment: your code is also would not evaluate to correct answer since you are not considering the *, / first

Comment: Do not repost the same question because you didn't like the answers. Edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should get the operation `*/-+`

Move `Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(0, i))` to a function e.g. getLeftArg

Do the same for `Integer.parseInt(exp.substring(i+1, exp.length()));`  e.g. getRightArg

then create new method with params leftArg, rightArg, operation

as rest of code is the same

i.e.

```
newResult= newMethod (leftArg, rightArg, operation)
```

which does your calculation plus `primeResult = newResult; System.out.println(primeResult);`

Answer (score 0):

Since Java doesn't have something like delegates, you won't be able to implement as a loop like you want to unless you define each operator in an Object. If you want the simplest possible code, here's a solution by Mauricio from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832933/performing-math-operation-when-operator-is-stored-in-a-string):

```
ScriptEngineManager scm = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = scm.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
double primeResult = (double)jsEngine.eval(exp);
```

Yes, getting a JavaScript engine to evaluate an arithmetic expression is a bit overkill. However, it obviously can handle multiple operators so you don't have to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant approach, for this kind of problem, would be use Polymorphism and enum types instead of switch statements.

This code below is from Effective Java - Chapter 6, Joshua Bloch.

```
public enum Operation {
    PLUS("+") {
        double apply(double x, double y) { return x + y; }
    },
    MINUS("-") {
        double apply(double x, double y) { return x - y; }
    };
    private final String symbol;
    Operation(String symbol) { this.symbol = symbol; }
    @Override public String toString() { return symbol; }

    abstract double apply(double x, double y);

    private static final Map<String, Operation> stringToEnum = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for(Operation op : values())
            stringToEnum.put(op.toString(), op);
    }
    public static Operation fromString(String symbol) {
        return stringToEnum.get(symbol);
    }
}
```

Then, to apply an operation:

```
 double result = Operation.fromString("+").apply(1, 1); // 2.0
 result = Operation.fromString("-").apply(1,1); // 0.0
```