# Writing an application that takes in 2 values and a operator and does the math

Tags: java, operators

I need to write an application which lets the user put in two values and an operator and then calculate it. If the operator is different form +,-,/ or * the application should prompt "Wrong operator input". When it's compiled it should run something like this:

Give me number 1: **5**

Give me number 2: **2**

Give me an operator: **+**

Result: **7**

The text in bold is userinput.

So far... I've got nothing. I mean I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1;
    int n2;
    String o;

    System.out.print("Give me number 1: ");
    n1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Give me number 2: ");
    n2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Give me an operator: ");
    o = input.nextLine();

  }

}
```

But that's about it. I have no idea how to proceed. The biggest question I have is: How do I get the users operator to be an actual operator?

Comment: What about a switch/case statement?

Comment: Create a `switch` in your code based on entered operator and actually program all 4 operations as its cases. Put your error message in `default`.

Comment: Possible dup:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832933/performing-math-operation-when-operator-is-stored-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like the below would suit your needs:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Give me number 1: ");
        int n1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Give me number 2: ");
        int n2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Give me an operator: ");
        String o = input.next();

        switch (o) {
        case "+":   
            System.out.println(n1 + n2);
            break;
        case "-":   
            System.out.println(n1 - n2);
            break;
        case "*":   
            System.out.println(n1 * n2);
            break;
        case "/":   
            System.out.println(n1 / n2);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Error, invalid operand.");
```

Comment: I get an error in the switch statement: "Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted".

Comment: Instead of using the complete string for the switch-statement, how about using only the first character of the string? It can be obtained by `String.charAt(int position)`

Comment: Nevermind. It was just a compile preference error. This solution works perfectly! Thank you.