# valueOf for an operator stored in Java String

Tags: java

I have an operator stored in a String. like this:

```
 String op="+";
```

How I can convert it to its main functionality? For example I have two numbers. I want to do calculations on those numbers based this operator.

But, I don't want to use a condition like `switch` to detect it is a `+` operator. I want to put that operator between that two number and calculation done automatically.

Something like this:

```
1.op.2 //3
```

How I can do that? I know in javascript we can do that but in java I can't. I know there solutions like **ScriptEngine** but I can use them. I need pure Java solution.

Comment: And i hope he is not asking the same question from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832933/performing-math-operation-when-operator-is-stored-in-a-string

Comment: @SanKrish OP don't want to use scriptengine.

Answer (score 0):

No, simply you cannot do that in Java (*there is a possibility with* `ScriptEngineManager`, *but you denied it*). Compiler needs to realize your operator at compile time itself.

Comment: I am wondering,how did you answer for a **duplicate** marked question ?

Comment: @SanKrish I clicked on submit, before it's closed as duplicate.