# Get input from user in one line without space in java

Tags: java

I am a beiggner in java programming and i have a problem i want to get input from user in one line such as in c++ 
in c++ if i want to make a calculator i make 2 variable for example `a` `b`and third is `op` and make user input them by

```
cin>>a>>op>>b;
if (op=='+')
{
    cout<<a+b<<endl;
}
```

and so on how to make that in Java ?
i make a try in java but i get Error
and one more question how to make user input a char i try char a=in.next(); but get error so i make it string 
code java

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int a=in.nextInt();
String op=in.nextLine();
int b=in.nextInt();
if (op=="+")
{
    System.out.println(a+b);
}
else if  (op=="-")
{
    System.out.println(a-b);
}
 .........
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: You can refer these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942701/take-a-char-input-from-the-scanner  AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832933/performing-math-operation-when-operator-is-stored-in-a-string

Comment: Thanks its helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Java you compare String with `a.equals(b)`, in you example it would be `op.equals("+")`. And also, after reading a line it have the line break character (\n), so you should remove it to avoid problems. Remove it using `String op = in.nextLine().replace("\n", "");`.

And answering the how to read a character part, you can use `char op = reader.next().charAt(0)`